# Read csv and write to mongodb using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose

I have a large csv and I need to read t and insert to mongodb

Csv contains  user name, category name and policy name.

Need to insert Users into User collection with category id and policy id. Csv provides only the category name and policy name. So I need to fetch category id from collection using its name.

If category name not exist, create a new one and returns its id. Same case for policy.

So I tried

```
    fs.createReadStream('./data_sheet.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', async (row) => {
        // console.log(row)
        let res = await Category.findOneOrCreate({ name: row.cat.trim() });
        console.log(res)

    })
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('CSV file successfully processed');
    });



categorySchema.statics.findOneOrCreate = async function findOneOrCreate(condition) {
try {
    const self = this
    let agent = await self.findOne(condition)
    console.log("condition")
    console.log(condition)
    console.log("agent")
    console.log(agent)
    if (agent) return agent._id
    else {
        agent = await self.create(condition)
        return agent._id
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

}

This is not working in proper manner. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *not working in proper manner*?

Comment: We can do it in a way that, make csv to array of json objects and loop over there.

Is there any any way to call this on 
`.on('data', async (row) => {
        // console.log(row)
        let res = await Category.findOneOrCreate({ name: row.cat.trim() });
        console.log(res)
})`

Thats my doubt. Or is it necessary to make an array and rest function?

Answer (score 0):

If by not working you mean, the data is not coming up for category then make sure you follow the right async approach or else provide more info.

There are several things to keep in mind,
You might need to create a cronjob for recursive process

1. Import the csv file into an array of Object
2. Loop over the object to match with category Id
3. If not then create a category Id
4. Return to the main function
5. update the document [here you can either update all or update one at a time using the step 2 looping we did]

Comment: We can do it in a way that, make csv to array of json objects and loop over there.

Is there any any way to call this on 
`.on('data', async (row) => {
        // console.log(row)
        let res = await Category.findOneOrCreate({ name: row.cat.trim() });
        console.log(res)
})`

Thats my doubt. Or is it necessary to make an array and rest function?

Comment: Let me clear it, you want your data event to be called as a separate function?

Comment: I need to read a csv and insert into db.

it contains category and insert into separate collection and use category id into user collection data